# looking for some good books in quantum algebra which will help in quantum information

Tags: reference-request, quantum-information

I want to take a [quantum algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algebra) route to take my previous study further which is related to quantum information. but unfortunately, I am unable to find enough material in this arena. can anyone suggest some research material or book for this?

Comment: What is "quantum algebra"?

Comment: @Rammus [quantum algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Jens Carsten Jantzen's *[Lectures on Quantum Groups](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-6/)* is a good resource for folks who are approaching quantum groups/algebras having studied the theory of complex semisimple Lie algebras. (In fact, Jantzen specifies in the preface that his target audience is those with exposure to linear algebra and the theory of semisimple Lie algebras.)

[Introduction to Quantum Groups and Crystal Bases](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-42/) by Jin Hong and Seok-Jin Kang
is another text which assumes less background knowledge of Lie algebras and Hopf algebras than many references.